# TinyMCE replace Html tags before submit

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I'm trying to replace the html tag '<' '>' with '&lt;' and '&gt;' in my text from TinyMCE before do the page postback.

With TinyMCE v.3.x i can do in this way:

```
function saveCallback(element_id, html, body) {
    html = html.replace(/</gi, "&lt;");
    html = html.replace(/>/gi, "&gt;");
    return html;
}

function loadCallback(type, value) {
    if (type == "insert_to_editor") {
        value = value.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
        value = value.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
    }
    return value;
}

tinyMCE.init({
 ...
 save_callback: "saveCallback",
 cleanup_callback: "loadCallback" 
});
```

with the new TinyMCE v.4.x i've try in this way:

```
$(function () {
    tinymce.init({
        language: "it",
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        formats: false,
        menubar: false,    
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "Testo",
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) {                            
                html = editor.getContent();
                html = html.replace(/</gi, "&lt;");
                html = html.replace(/>/gi, "&gt;");
                editor.getElement().value = html;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and in this way:

```
$(function () {
    tinymce.init({
        language: "it",
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        formats: false,
        menubar: false,    
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "Testo",
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('submit', function (e) {                            
                html = editor.getContent();
                html = html.replace(/</gi, "&lt;");
                html = html.replace(/>/gi, "&gt;");
                editor.getElement().value = html;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But the postback values always contain the html tag and the page return the message "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following options in the **init**

```
encoding : 'xml',
setup: function (editor) {editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) {e.content = e.content.replace(/&#39/g, '&apos');});}
```

FYI: adapted from your code above and ref:

http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2012/05/21/asp-net-4-0-tinymce-and-ldquoa-potentially-dangerous-request.aspx

works for me :) , hope it helps.

Comment: I have modified in this way, and now it's ok

    encoding: 'xml',                        
    setup: function (editor) { editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) { e.content = e.content.replace(/&#39/g, '&apos').replace(/&amp;/g, '&'); }); }

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. :D

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#MySelector",
    width: ...,
    height: ...,
    encoding: 'xml',                        
    setup: function (editor) { editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) { e.content = e.content.replace(/&#39/g, '&apos').replace(/&amp;/g, '&'); }); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With tinyMCE 4 try this clean solution, using the [PostProcess](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/advanced/events/#postprocess) event:

```
    tinymce.init({
    language: "it",
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    formats: false,
    menubar: false,    
    mode: "exact",
    elements: "Testo",                
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            editor.on('PostProcess', function (e) {
                e.content = e.content.replace(/</g, '&lt');
                e.content = e.content.replace(/>/g, '&gt');
            });
        },
});
```